# getting address instead of struct values

Tags: c, struct

I am having trouble getting integer values from a struct via a pointer, instead of getting the intended value am getting pointer address.

I am in main.c

```
struct sonicPins *args1;



int main(){
pthread_t thr1, thr2, thr3, thr4;
//void(*foo1)(int, int, int);
//void(*foo2)(void *args);
//foo1 = &calcSonicS;
//foo2 = &threadFunc;

args1 = malloc(sizeof(struct sonicPins));

args1->trig1 = 21;
args1->echo1 = 20;
//front right.
args1->trig2 = 16;
args1->echo2 = 12;
//rear left;
args1->trig3 = 26;
args1->echo3 = 19;
//rear right.
args1->trig4 = 13;
args1->echo4 = 6;
//printf("print args %d", args1.trig1);
//if(args1!=NULL){
 pthread_create(&thr1, NULL, &threadFunc,(void*) &args1);
//}
```

sonicThread.h

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<sys/time.h>
#include<wiringPi.h>

typedef struct sonicPins{
//front left.
int trig1;
int echo1;
//front right.
int trig2;
int echo2;
//rear left;
int trig3;
int echo3;
//rear right.
int trig4;
int echo4;
}args;

extern void* threadFunc(void *sonicPinsPtr);


void* threadFunc(void  *sonicPinsPtr)
{

    struct sonicPins *args = sonicPinsPtr;
    int trig = args->trig1;
    int echo = args->echo1;
    printf("threadFunc got  trigger value: %d and echo value %d\n", echo, trig);
    value = setup(trig, echo);
    printf("distance measured %d\n", value);
}
```

Printing the distance will not work at this stage due to the echo and trig not getting their intended pin value. The other print test is out putting incorrect values entirely.

Its outputting

```
threadFunc got  trigger value: 0 and echo value 26222600
```

Should only be 2 digit integers, I have no idea how to fix this issue.

Comment: `args1` is a pointer, you're passing a pointer to that, so you're getting a pointer to pointer to `struct sonicPins`. Also you probably didn't mean to `typedef` `struct sonicPins` to `args`.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra level of indirection when you pass `args1` to `pthread_create`. `args1` is already a pointer.

Change:

```
pthread_create(&thr1, NULL, &threadFunc,(void*) &args1);
```

to:

```
pthread_create(&thr1, NULL, &threadFunc,(void*) args1);
```

Comment: Hopefully that "not" was a typo for "now" ?

Comment: Am actually new to C and followed examples and other people like yourself giving me advise.

Comment: Well good luck - keep plugging away at it - remember it takes around 10,000 hours to become good at anything worthwhile. ;-)

Comment: Thanks I totally agree took me a while to learn Java and PHP etc.